# Can i change language to a specific element in Superio Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have installed Superio Theme, i have to translate to my native language, but i cannot change some elements
[image]
This Theme has some custom elements they made, they are called APUS. and i cant find place where to change language.

I tried to change language in wordpress panel, it changed some things, but not those above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do it manually.
For at once (Language translation): Simply install Free GTranslate WordPress Plugin and do the Setup for your required languages (Google it for installation and setup help). Clear WordPress Cache, Clear your browser cache and then check(or use incognito mode to check).

For advanced translation you can purchase premium edition of GTranslate or WPML  WordPress Plugin if required (first check the free edition of GTranslate).